# API callback setup for scheduling a job

Tags: architecture, scheduled-tasks

I'm devising an API that allows a remote system to execute a job/report at my server(s). This is easy enough, but the job typically takes too long for the caller to wait for. After the job or report is finished I would like the scheduler to check back to pick the results/report up.

I can easily do one of the following:

1. Send the user an email to let him know the job is done, with details on how to pick it up (but that would be difficult to act on automatically for him)
2. Use a callback link that he supplies me with to post the location of the rsults/report to
3. Supply a link that he can poll periodically to get the results

Maybe there are other ways for this? If so - what is the recommend way to implement such a setup?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a combination of `2.` and `3.`. Let him provide a callback that you will POST the results to once they are available and you can also provide an endpoint that he could poll for the progress of the operation. This could be useful if he needed to show some progress to his clients.

Comment: Thanks - do you know of any standards or good widely-used examples that I should look at? Especially for the way that I should use the callback, because it's important that a user can implement his own callback easily